# Change values in a column Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of tweets that I am looping through. I am comparing it to a list of company names (which I am reading from another file). I want to search for these companies in the tweets, and if the tweet contains one of the companies, I want to add the company the tweet contains in a separate column called Company. The Company column is already created, with the default value of None.  This is the code I currently have. It manages to find the companies in the tweets (when I use a print), but I cannot figure out how to replace the value in the Company column. The df['Company'].replace(Null, lookup) function does not seem to work either.

```
#read tweets
df = pd.read_excel(r'tweets.xlsx', dtype={'Nr of retweets':int, 'Nr of favorited':int})
tweets = df['Tweet'].tolist()

#create new column
df['Company'] = None
companies = df['Ticker'].tolist()

#read words to search for
data = pd.read_excel(r'lookup.companies.xlsx')
lookups = data['lookup'].tolist()
    
for tweet in tweets:
   for lookup in lookups:
      if lookup in tweet:
         *insert something here to change value in the 'Company' column*
```

This is the current output when I print the df. So the aim is to change the values in 'Company' to the specific company mentioned in the tweet (which is found in the lookups array). Not all tweets contain a company, so for those tweets, I want to keep the default value of None (or 0 or something).
[image]

Comment: can you post a part of your df and your expected output?

Comment: Can we see some more code? Are you using Pandas? Is Word a list or a Pandas series?

Comment: Is this sufficient?